# pandas read_excel select rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

thanks to StackOverflow (so basically all of you) I've managed to solve almost all my issues regarding reading excel data to DataFrame, except one... My code goes like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel(
    fileName,
    sheetname=sheetName,
    header=None,
    skiprows=3,
    index_col=None,
    skip_footer=0,
    parse_cols='A:J,AB:CC,CE:DJ',
    na_values='')
```

The thing is that in excel files which I'm parsing last row of dataI want to load is every time on different position. The only way I can identify last row of data  which interest me is to look for word "SUMA" in first column of each sheet, and the last row I want to load to df will be n-1 row from the one containing "SUMA". Rows below SUMA also have some irrevelant (for me) information and there can by quite a lot of them so I want to avoid loading them.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it with generators, you could do something like this. This loads the complete DataFrame, but afterwards filters out the lines after 'SUMA', using the trick that `True == 1`, so you only keep the relevant info. You might need some work afterwards to get the dtypes correct

```
def read_files(files):
    sheetname = 'my_sheet'
    for file in files:
        yield pd.read_excel(
            file,
            sheetname=sheetName,
            header=None,
            skiprows=3,
            index_col=None,
            skip_footer=0,
            parse_cols='A:J,AB:CC,CE:DJ',
            na_values='')

def clean_files(dataframes):
    summary_text = 'SUMA'
    for df in dataframes:
        index_after_suma = df.index.str.startswith(summary_text).cumsum()
        yield df.loc[~index_after_suma, :]
```